# Python argument parser list of list or tuple of tuples

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to use argument parser to parse a 3D coordinate so I can use

```
--cord 1,2,3 2,4,6 3,6,9
```

and get

```
((1,2,3),(2,4,6),(3,6,9))
```

My attempt is

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--cord', help="Coordinate", dest="cord", type=tuple, nargs=3)
args = parser.parse_args(["--cord","1,2,3","2,4,6","3,6,9"])

vars(args) 
{'cord': [('1', ',', '2', ',', '3'),
  ('2', ',', '4', ',', '6'),
  ('3', ',', '6', ',', '9')]}
```

What would the replacement of the comma be?

Comment: +1 for showing your attempt and for using the standard lib instead of reinventing

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can add your own [type](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#type). This also allows for additional validations, for example:

```
def coords(s):
    try:
        x, y, z = map(int, s.split(','))
        return x, y, z
    except:
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError("Coordinates must be x,y,z")


parser.add_argument('--cord', help="Coordinate", dest="cord", type=coords, nargs=3)
```

Comment: +1 Thanks!  Have changed the raise to a TypeError.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: since this case is a `3D` coordinate `nargs=3` is obvious, but if your case doesn't require a fixed number of tuples, you can use `nargs='+'`

Answer (score 0):

For my problem, I had to have a more general approach, not linked to the number of inputs.

Starting from the great answer by georg, I solved my problem as follows

```
# additional type
def coords(s):
    seps = r'[ ;.]'
    try:
        situp = []
        for si in re.split(seps, s):
            situp.append(tuple(map(int, si.split(','))))
        return situp
    except:
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError("Coordinates must be given divided by commas and space, dot, or semicolon e.g.: 'x,y k,l,m'")
```

With this, an input like `1,2 3,4,5` will be turned in a list of tuples like `[(1,2), (3,4,5)]`

**EDIT:** It might be that the for loop is not optimal, but I wrote it to avoid the use of `nargs`

**EDIT 2:**

1. to have a list of list, one should change

   the line `situp.append(tuple(map(int, si.split(','))))`

   with `situp.append(list(map(int, si.split(','))))`
2. to have a tuple of uples one can just change the return with

   `return tuple(situp)`